# Is an autogenerated, opt-out email legally binding

Tags: contract-law

A software company are refusing to cancel a subscription product I have with them which renewed in 16th July 2017 unless I pay a £239.40 early cancellation fee. The subscription began in 2014.

They have no record of my approval, just a record that I didn't disapprove it.

[image]

They also refuse to cancel it in the future, and obviously cannot cancel it in the past.

[image]

Where do I stand with this sort of behaviour?

Comment: Usually the way such things work is that when you first sign up for the service, you agree that it will be automatically renewed unless you notify them in a specific way (and perhaps during a specific time period) that you wish to cancel.  You probably were sent (or shown) some sort of contract or agreement at the time you first signed up in 2014.  So this would be the time to go back and read it, and see what you agreed to.

Comment: If the auto-renewal is part of that agreement, then their autogenerated opt-out email would have only been a courtesy, and would be of no legal significance.